# Dynamically assign attributes to objects from outside

Tags: object-oriented, python

In python the following code works perfectly fine.

```py
class Table:
    pass

table = Table()

table.fruits = ["apple", "orange"]
```

But as soon as we check it out with some kind of linter, errors will start showing. Pylint will complain about attribute defined outside `__init__` method, Mypy will claim we're trying to access attribute that doesn't exist etc.

Meanwhile, there are situations when the logic of our program suggests that this is the most appropriate way. Let's say we have a Playground class object, where we store different information's, depending on to which subclass of the Game class, implementing logic of the game being played on it, we pass it to.

Creating a subclass is not a solution if there are reasons to recycle the same object over and over again. Using a dict underneath makes it possible to silence errors, but it seems to be a trick rather than the right solution, since this type was designed to map two collections of objects.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: Using a dictionary is not "a trick", it is the usual solution to this kind of problem I would start with when using a strictly typed language. But I am wondering by myself if in Python there is an approach to solve this with instance attributes without simply disabling the specific linter rule (which could be also a solution).

Comment: @DocBrown I feel like it's a trick, because from what I understand, original intention was to use dict as a mapping structure, where all keys are the same type and all values are the same type. I know this was often other way around, for example with JSON, and in recent version of python we have TypedDicts for the purpose of using dicts more like classes, but it still is considered just a data structure. And my question is what if we want something more than just a data structure, if we want to have some methods coupled with it.

Answer (score 0):

`Playground` is a dictionary. Linters tell you to make that explicit. It will help to understand the program later.